# Oracle SQL Custom Function Error

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am making a custom function to return the max of a row in a table:

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getMax
     RETURN DECIMAL(3,2)
     IS l_getMax DECIMAL(3,2);
        BEGIN
            SELECT MAX(PRICE)
            INTO l_getMax
            FROM TABLE;
        RETURN l_getMax;
   END getMax;
```

It compiled just fine when I made the data type an integer but then I realized it should be a decimal and when I changed that I get the following errors:

```
 Error(2,18): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following:     . @ % ; is authid as cluster order using external character    deterministic parallel_enable pipelined aggregate    result_cache 

 Error(3,4): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IS" when expecting one of the following:     , * & - + / at mod remainder rem <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <an exponent (**)> as    from into || multiset bulk year day 

 Error(9,16): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     end not pragma final instantiable order overriding static    member constructor map
```

Comment: Just make it a `number`.  Oracle is very flexible about `numbers`.

Comment: `RETURN DECIMAL(3,2)` should be `RETURN DECIMAL`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, can you please put it as an answer?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried that but it's rounding up the answer for me. The max is 1.99 and the function returns 2.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks! The number datatype kept the decimal places, Make it a comment and I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: That's a display issue, not a calculation issue

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so what can I do to fix the display issue?

Comment: @eatsleepcode use `to_char()` to format it or configure your SQL client to show more decimals digits

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
create table t(
 col DECIMAL(3,2)
);

insert into t values (3.2);
insert into t values (2.1);
insert into t values (1.99);


   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getMax
     RETURN NUMBER
     AS 
      l_getMax DECIMAL(3,2);
     BEGIN
            SELECT MAX(col) INTO l_getMax FROM t;
        RETURN l_getMax;
     END getMax;
     /

   select getMax from dual;
```